# Clustering documents - how to evaluate results?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, model-evaluations, dbscan

I'm using DBSCAN clustering on a set of documents. The documents' content was converted to TF-IDF matrix, and **I'd like to find consistent ways to evaluate the clusters when no added information is given (labels etc.)**.

1. **Metrics comparing clusters** - a score for each cluster - the goal here is to figure out which clusters are 'better' than others (more dense and more unique). Thought of two metrics:

   *Intra-cluster similarity - measure the similarity of documents inside each cluster - I used the cosine distances between documents in the TF-IDF representation

   *Inter-cluster similarity - measure the similarity between clusters (to highlight the more unique clusters) - similarly, planning to use the cosine distances between clusters' kernels
2. **Metrics comparing clustering algorithms** - a score for the clustering technique (such as Silhouette score). Will be used for hyper-parameter tuning and choosing an algorithm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

None of the internal evaluation metrics will work well on *text* in my experience. Probably because of the curse of dimensionality.

Furthermore, DBSCAN does not cluster everything, but can also produce noise points. Few evaluation methods (and even fewer  implementations...) handle it well that **noise is *not* a cluster**.

Comment: Clustering textual files with very similar format, I already tested different  algorithms, and so far DBSCAN produced satisfying results. Do you know any metric that can be useful as a rule of thumb?

Comment: There is DBCV for DBSCAN type clusters.